# How to call "send" on java object instead of Ruby's builtin "send"?

Tags: ruby, jruby

Ruby objects all have a "send" method, however, I'm trying to use a Java library ([netty-tools](https://github.com/cgbystrom/netty-tools/blob/master/src/main/java/se/cgbystrom/netty/http/websocket/WebSocketClient.java)) which has a 'send' method on one of its interfaces.

The usage should be `java_obj.send 'some data'` but that doesn't work b/c ruby's `send` is getting invoked, not the `send` from the Java interface in netty-tools. Is there some way of calling the send method from the Java library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *should* be able to use `java_send`, roughly:

```
java_obj.java_send :send 'some data'
```

[Here are some additional usage details (e.g., overloaded methods)](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#calling-masked-or-unreachable-java-methods-with-java_send).